# Building a Warehouse/Inventory management system, with multiple locations for each item

Tags: java, object-oriented, object-oriented-design

I am building a **WMS** with the following basic requirements:

1. Each **Item** can be in multiple **Location**s.
2. A **Location** can contain multiple **Item**s.
3. For each **Location** / **item** combination, I must be able to track:
   **QtyOnHand**, **QtyReserved**, and **QtyAvailable**.
4. One **Location** can contain another **Location**.

The basic required behaviour of a Location, is:

1. Adding/Removing an **Item** with a **Quantity**.
2. Adding/Removing a nested **Location**.
3. Tracking Quantities for each **Item** within the **Location**.

I am attempting to write the code while staying faithful to OOP design principles, namely:

1. Designing class interfaces to  reflect **behaviour** rather than **data**.
2. Avoiding **Getter**/**Setter**s.
3. **Tell, don't Ask**, as much as possible.

With that in mind, here is the basic code for a Location:

```
public class Location{

    private final Map<InventoryItem, Integer> items = new HashMap<>();
    private final Set<Location> locations = new HashSet<>();

    public void add(InventoryItem item, int quantity) {
         if (items.containsKey(item)) {
             InventoryQuantity inventoryQuantity = items.get(item);
             items.put(item, inventoryQuantity.addQuantityOnHand(quantity));
         } else {
             items.put(item, quantity);
         }
    }

    public void add(Location location) {
        locations.add(location);
    }

    public void remove(InventoryItem item, int quantity) {
        if (items.keySet().contains(item)) {
            if ((items.get(item) - quantity) == 0) {
                items.remove(item);
            } else {
                items.put(item, items.get(item) - quantity);
            }
        }
    }

    public void remove(Location location) {
        locators.remove(location);
    }

}
```

So I now that I have the basic behaviour for Adding/Removing, I am having difficulty figuring out what would be the best way to track quantity. I could create an **InventoryQuantity** class, as follows:

```
 public class InventoryQuantity {

    private InventoryItem item;

    private int quantityOnHand;

    private int quantityReserved;

    private int quantityAvailable;

    public InventoryItem getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public void setItem(InventoryItem item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    public int getQuantityOnHand() {
        return quantityOnHand;
    }

    public void setQuantityOnHand(int quantityOnHand) {
        this.quantityOnHand = quantityOnHand;
    }

    public int getQuantityReserved() {
        return quantityReserved;
    }

    public void setQuantityReserved(int quantityReserved) {
        this.quantityReserved = quantityReserved;
    }

    public int getQuantityAvailable() {
        return quantityAvailable;
    }

    public void setQuantityAvailable(int quantityAvailable) {
        this.quantityAvailable = quantityAvailable;
    }
}
```

and store one **InventoryQuantity** for each **InventoryItem** in **Location**, like so:

```
private final Map<InventoryItem, InventoryQuantity> items = new HashMap<>();
```

My questions/issues are as follows:

1. **InventoryQuantity** does not seem to be a real world object with a defined     **behavior**; rather, it seems to be a **data structure** with the sole purpose of storing quantity **data** (as evidenced by the existance of Getter/Setters); is there a better way?
2. Is asking a location to **getQuantityOnHandForItem(item)** a violation of **Tell, don't Ask**? On the other hand, there does not seem to be a better way of retreiving data...

I actually had some more questions, but this is what I remember at the moment. If anyone can help me understand/apply the principles effectively, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: I'm a bit confused by a Location containing a set of locations.  What is going on there?  Why is Locations a recursive structure?  What purpose does that serve?  And what does a "locater" do?

Comment: @Robert Harvey that was actually supposed to be location, not locator; edited accordingly. As to your question, the reason I would nest Locations is    for locations within locations, such as a shelf in a rack in an aisle in warehouse; such that one location can contain others.

Comment: I would favor something a bit more flat and explicit, like shelf, rack, aisle and custom fields in the Location object.  It's going to make your life much simpler.

Comment: Your "remove" Method has some unexpected behavior. It doesn't check if I'm removing more items than I have on stock, so I can end up with negative amounts of stuff.

Comment: @Tsar there is thinking in Inventory Management that says to allow for that to happen

Comment: @Robert Harvey It would be simpler, yes, but now I can ask for the total quantity of any location in the heirarchy; for instance, I can ask for the total quantity in a specific rack, which would sum the quantities of each shelf within the rack.

Comment: @IntelliData Negative inventory is usually used as a hack to solve "soon-to-be-there" stuff that may never come and you end up with a heck of a problem. I solved this on one of my older jobs by using the factory as a warehouse - products that were currently in the line of production where "stored" on the factory with an increased delivery time. This helped me to avoid a lot of headaches!

Comment: @Tsar in the past, negative inventory has helped me track errors; whenever I would see negative qty, I knew something was off, and I would look deeper.

Comment: @IntelliData That doesn't mean your system should allow it. The correct behavior for this type of thing would be to throw up a exception saying "Nope, can't do that with those parameters" and prevent the error from happening in the first place. _Inconsistent State_ is a _Very Bad Thing_.

Comment: @Tsar Agreed. Duly noted, and will be taken care of. Thanks! : )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53709/discussion-between-intellidata-and-tsar).

Comment: Typically stroagelocations are simple relations between one storagelocation and many products. One storagelocation in a warehouse could be encoded with a scheme like **L1AA000001**: Meaning _site_: L1, _section_: AA, _rack_: 00, and a _row-column_-based scheme: e.g. _row_: 00, _column_: 01. No need for recursive storagelocation data structures.

Comment: @Thomas Junk reason i chose recursive is because I can now ask  any location in the heirarchy for all the quantity below it; for eaxmple, I can ask a rack for the sum of qty between all its shelves.

Comment: Which you could too many with above encoding scheme (each semantic part distributed to a separate column) ☺️ no magic involved here.

Answer (score 2):

Would it make sense in your system to have a class like this:

```
public class QuantifiedInventoryItem extends InventoryItem
{
    private int quantityOnHand;

    private int quantityReserved;

    private int quantityAvailable;

    /* getters and setters for fields above, if necessary */
}
```

I agree that it seems a *little* weird to have an object like the `InventoryQuantity` as you have it above. It has no behaviour, and does not map to a real-world object.

A *quantified* `InventoryItem` can map to a real-world object (well, it maps better than `InventoryQuantity`): an inventory item with known quantities, maybe even at specific locations.

As far as:

> Is asking a location to getQuantityOnHandForItem(item) a violation of Tell, don't Ask?

No, I don't think that's a violation. I think "Tell, Don't Ask" refers more to situations where you have complex logic that depends on the internal state of an object, and that state is accessed via many getters. The pricinciple refers to moving that logic/behaviour *into* the object, since that's where the data that drives it already resides.

In the case of `getQuantityOnHandForItem`, you're not asking about specific behaviour driven by this function, so the simple existence of the function is probably not a problem. If you had a set of logic statements that constantly called a `Location`'s getters, it might be worth considering refactoring that logic to a new function *within* the `Location`.

See: https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html

Comment: Yes, I figured the answer to TDA would be along those lines, although the name 'TDA' would at first glance suggest 'always tell, never ask'... did the originators of TDA have in mind what you said?

Comment: @IntelliData You can also read about [Command Query Separation](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CommandQuerySeparation.html). Note that it is kind of the opposite of TDA, so both approaches have their pros and cons. If you notice something that is purely a "query" (it returns information, and does not modify the state, and it is not being used as part of a bigger command that modifies state), it is not a violation of TDA's rule about "getter".

Comment: I'm kinda with rwong here.  Tell, Don't Ask is a *guideline* I follow when I'm writing a class that has *behaviors.*  If I'm just doing CRUD operations, I don't even think about Tell, Don't Ask.

Comment: @Robert Harvey one of my questions actually was whether it is at all OK to have a class with only getter/setters and no behavior. I just read an article from Martin Fowler, where he says it's a code smell :(.

Comment: Data Transfer Objects are used all the time, in real, working, production applications.  Fowler also says that DTO's have their appropriate uses.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner my **InventoryQuantity** class is actually exactly like your **QuantifiedInventoryItem** class, except that you extend **InventoryItem** while I compose it...

Comment: @Robert Harvey is **InventoryQuantity** which I use to **store** the data in the **Location** object considered a **DTO**?

Comment: Yes, it is, though you got the name of the class wrong.  I would have thought `InventoryItem` would contain those fields, actually.

Comment: @IntelliData: the name `InventoryQuantity` implies an object that is just a bunch of numbers - not a real-world object. Having this object be composed with an actual `InventoryItem` seems very weird. What does this object represent - numbers of a thing, or the thing itself? The name `QuantifiedInventoryItem` refers to a real-world object, with an associated quantity, and since it extends `InventoryItem` it *is* an `InventoryItem`.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner You are right that I should probably rename the class, but I have another problem with your solution in that the quantified class represents one item with quantities, while in my case I need the item to appear in many different locations with qty tracked separately for each location.

Comment: @IntelliData: I guess if my class represents a quantified item with no specific location - could you have a `List<QuantifiedInventoryItem>` within a `Location`? That way the `Location` knows which `QuantifiedInventoryItem`s it has (and also how many).

Comment: @IntelliData: Perhaps instead of `private final Map<InventoryItem, Integer> items = new HashMap<>();`, have `private List<QuantifiedInventoryItem> items = new ArrayList<QuantifiedInventoryItem>();`

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner which is really very similar to what I initially suggested, which brings me back to the question of a class with no behavior...

Comment: @IntelliData: `QuantifiedInventoryItem` inherits from `InventoryItem`. It can have all the behaviour of `InventoryItem` because it *is* an `InventoryItem`. `InventoryQuantity` is *not* an `InventoryItem` - it *contains* one, but it is private and there is no code that I can see that makes use of it, other than a getter and setter, so while it may look similar, it is *not* the same. `InventoryItem` *has* a member which has behaviour but in what is shown here, it does not make use of this.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner So why would I inherit from InventoryItem, if I can have the same InvntoryItem in many places but One quantifiedItem cn be in only one place?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53751/discussion-between-intellidata-and-frustratedwithformsdesigner).